# Get original text of Common Criteria protection profile

Tags: compliance, certification, common-criteria

In translated from an English profile, combined from a couple of profiles (I found that one is Protection Profile for Application Software v1.2 of NIAP) I have something like

> "TOE security functions must provide for the preliminary
> initialization of variables and data structures when allocating RAM."

Could anyone tell me where can I find the original text of this? With evaluation if possible.